# Reset a modified list to previous value on iPython

Tags: python

I'd like to substitue `'(', ')'` with `'[', ']'` in the folliwing list using slicing.

```
    # the raw data 
    square = ['(', ')', '.', '^', '-']
    # the result I want
    square = ['[', ']', '.', '^', '-']
```

Replace with slicing method

```
    In [45]: square[:1] = ['[', ']']
    In [46]: square
    Out[46]: ['[', ']', ']', '.', '^', '-']
  # sliced with wrong index, it should be [:2]
```

I have to manipulate on the modified square like:

```
 square.remove(']')
```

Or re-assign to square manually

```
    In [47]: square = ['(', ')', '.', '^', '-']
        ...: square[:2] = ['[', ']']
    In [48]: square
    Out[48]: ['[', ']', '.', '^', '-']
```

During the process, how to reset the modified `square` to its unmodified status?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but the list maintains no knowledge of previous state. There is no "reset".

Comment: ty, I am clear on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new list from the old one using list()

```
square = ['(', ')', '.', '^', '-']
backup_square = list(square)
# Here I take the 1st value from square list and I put different data in it
square[0] = "DIFFERENT VALUE"
```

You will then be able to access the previous version of square in backup_square

```
print backup_square
>>> ['(', ')', '.', '^', '-']
```